# Using Jsoup, select the element that comes after a text

Tags: jsoup

An HTML page is something as follows:

```
bananas
<myTag ...> ... </myTag>
```

The `myTag` tag does not have an `id` or `name`. How can I select it, given only the information that it comes after the text `bananas`?

Sure you can select the tag by counting the placement order of all `myTag` elements, but I am asking the cleanest way in the case of no `id` or `name` or any other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options I can see:

#### Option 1: Use CSS query

The Jsoup CSS engine doesn't permit text node selection. However, you can use this option *if and only if* `myTag` and `bananas` have the **same** parent element.

```
:containsOwn(bananas) > myTag
```

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/~FenIgEjMXVQrUXpsUGGAJYEGAqU)

***DESCRIPTION***

```
:containsOwn(bananas) /* Select any element (1) having a TextNode as direct 
                         child containing bananas */
> myTag               /* Select child elements of (1) with tag name myTag */
```

#### Option 2: Visit all nodes

This option involves more code writing. You can act in three steps:

1. Visit manually each node in the document (see [NodeVisitor](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/NodeVisitor.html)).
2. IF a `TextNode` is found and contains `bananas`
   THEN move to 3.
   ELSE visit next node.
3. IF `TextNode` has a sibling node with name `myTag`
   THEN a myTag node has been found; visit next node
   ELSE visit next node.